# Parsing XML in Hebrew language

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I'm using NSXMLParser in iphone app that I'm working on.
Later I'm displaying the text in a view.
All is well when I'm using english language in my XML.
But my XML is in Herbrew language. I'm not able to read the text properly and display it.Please advice me what change do I've to make in XML.

Comment: What does it mean that you are “not able to read the text properly and display it”? Strip down the XML to the smallest version that does not work and paste it here. Do the same with the code.

Comment: I'm trying to past the whole xml (just 50 lines), but in the preview, its skipping elements.

Answer (score 1):

if the XML file is in UTF-8 and you are decoding it using NSUTF8Encoding you should have no problems.
when displaying the strings in UI, remember to set the correct alignment, or the right-to-left will not look correct.

Comment: How can I find out whether my XML file is UTF-8 encoding or not?

Comment: Well, two ways - either u have BOM characters at the beginning of the file (0xFE and 0xFF), or if it's a file without BOM, you have to just open it in some text editor/viewer that allows you to switch encodings and see which one it is.